# I can't get consecutive canvas rectangles to have the duplicate linear-gradient in js. Anyone know how?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, linear-gradients

I drew a canvas with consecutive rectangles each with it's own linear-gradient, but I am unable to make the linear-gradient show up on the rectangles except in the first rectangle. Each rectangle is the same size and every rectangle should have the same linear gradient. I was able to make only the first rectangle have the correct gradient, but none of the rest have it. The rest are black. Been looking all over the internet and can't find the answer. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

Here is a pen with my code: https://codepen.io/monamoves/pen/RQvzOe

And here it is again.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="fabric" width="1020" height="300">
</canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
  border: thin red solid;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
var cvs = document.getElementById("fabric");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var xcoordinate = 0;
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(xcoordinate, 0, xcoordinate + 20, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#ccc";
  ctx.moveTo(xcoordinate, 0);
  ctx.rect(xcoordinate, 0, 20, 300);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "black");
  ctx.fill();
  xcoordinate = xcoordinate + 20;  
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to move `ctx.createLinearGradient` into the loop so that it picks up the change in the value of `xcoordinate`?

Comment: @Dan D. Thanks so much! I tried that a while back with some other stuff that wasn't working and forgot to try that again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your gradient once to be over your first rectangle only. Gradients don't follow your shape, if you tell it to be 20px wide at coords 0,0 every shape drawn outside these coordsa will be one of the 2 extreme colors you did set.

You could create a new gradient at every iteration inside your for loop, and actually you would have to do so if you wanted to change its colorStops.

But the best solution in your case (single gradient) is to declare only once your gradient, set only once its colorStops, and simply modify the transformation matrix of your context; gradients are also affected.

```js
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var xcoordinate = 0;
// set all this only once if it doesn't change
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 0);
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
grd.addColorStop(1, "black");
ctx.strokeStyle="#ccc";

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  // we move the transform matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,xcoordinate,0);
  // and draw always at same coords
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 20, 300);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  xcoordinate = xcoordinate + 20;  
}
```

```html
<canvas id=cvs></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Path and render transforms

When you create a path it uses the transform that is current when the path function is called, and when you use the fill, or stroke you can set another transform.

This allows you to use separate coordinate systems, one for the shape and one for the fill and one for the stroke.

This particularly useful if you use separate styles for the fill and stroke.

### Example fit gradients to path

The example shows two gradients scaled and translated to fit the fill and the stroke of 3 shapes created in their own coordinate system.

There is one caveat with strokes.  `lineWidth` is a style and is transformed by current transform when `stroke` is called. This limits you to only using a uniform scale, and you must invert the `lineWidth` size. See how in code.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const grad1 = [[0, "green"], [0.45, "gold"], [0.55, "gold"], [1, "green"]];
const grad2 = [[0, "red"], [0.25, "black"], [0.75, "black"], [1, "red"]];
const addColStops = (g,s) => s.forEach(s => g.addColorStop(...s));
const style = {lineWidth: 5};

//==============================================================
// fill gradient
style.fillStyle = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 0);
// to simplify I attach the coords to the gradient so that it can be scaled to
// fit the rendered content
style.fillStyle.coords = { w: 20, h: 0 };
addColStops(style.fillStyle, grad1);

//==============================================================
// stroke gradient
style.strokeStyle = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20);
style.strokeStyle.coords = { w: 0, h: 20 };
addColStops(style.strokeStyle, grad2);

//==============================================================
// 3 example boxes
drawBox(10, 10, 60, 130, style);
style.lineWidth += 4;
drawBox(90, 10, 80, 130, style);
style.lineWidth += 8;
drawBox(200, 10, 140, 130, style);

//==============================================================
// draw box
function drawBox(x, y, width, height, style) {

  // shape drawn in default coordinates 
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // default transform
  Object.assign(ctx, style); // set the style

  //============================================================
  // create the shape
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);

  //============================================================
  // Make the gradient fit the stroke
  const s = style.strokeStyle.coords;

  // uniform scale for strokes only and correct for line width
  var scale = (width + ctx.lineWidth) / (s.w ? s.w : 1);
  if (s.w === 0) { scale = (height + ctx.lineWidth) / (s.h ? s.h : 1) }
  ctx.setTransform(
    scale, 0, 0, scale,
    x - ctx.lineWidth / 2, // correct for line width
    y - ctx.lineWidth / 2
  );
  // invert the lineWidth to correct its scale
  ctx.lineWidth /= scale;
  ctx.stroke();

  //============================================================
  // Make the fill gradient fit the rect
  const f = style.fillStyle.coords;
  ctx.setTransform(
    width / (f.w ? f.w : 1), // scale grad width if needed
    0, 0,
    height / (f.h ? f.h : 1), // scale grad heigh if needed
    x, y
  );
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width="400"></canvas>
```